# Laravel get table manes belonging to user with columns eager loaded

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have an application where a user creates tables for data storing. The table names are prefixed:

```
$user->id . "_table_name"
```

I can retrieve all tables that belong to this user like this:

```
$tables = DB::select("SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$user->id} . _%'");
```

And I can get the columns for each table like this:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing($table);
```

But I want to eager load the columns for each table, something like:

```
$tables = DB::with('columns')->select("SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$user->id} . _%'");
```

How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant, but it works:

```
$tables = DB::select("SHOW TABLES");

foreach($tables as $table) {
    $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($table->Tables_in_apiapi);
    $table->columns =  $columns;
}
```